# Requirements for assignment operator

Tags: c++

My question is quite simple but, actually, I can't find any information about this. Does copy (move) assignment operator require assignee to be constructed?

Comment: Basically there are no requirements AFAIK, just that the function signature must match, so the compiler will pick it up. What is more interesting is how you want to assign to an unconstructed object? Call the operator in constructor?

Comment: Bit more details please

Comment: You mean if in `a = b`, `a` is required to be a valid object? Yes, both `a` and `b` should be valid objects.

Comment: @Jefffrey What do you mean by should? It is quite hard to write a code that doesn't guarantee it (unless really calling operator from constructor) and I don't think any compiler would trip, although I am not sure. I haven't tested it. Whether the code would have any sense at all is another thing; most certainly not.

Comment: @luk32 It possible to allocate memory for object without calling constructor.

Comment: @alphashooter: Not really. You can allocate memory without calling any constructor `T` but then _you do not have a `T`_. So how do you intend to call a member function (the copy assignment operator) on an object that does not exist? This question requires far more detail on what specific case you are interested in.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well, maybe I just don't understand something, but it doesn't seems to be correct. If object is not constructed, it doesn't mean you can't call member functions. For example, you can just allocate memory for object of trivial type and, it seems, any call of member function of this object will have well-defined behavior, won't it?

Comment: @alphashooter: Why would it? You can call member functions on objects that exist, not on objects that don't exist. You seem to be inventing a new category of objects that exist but haven't been constructed, which as far as I can tell is non-sensical. But the rules for placement new may help you here so, as I said before, you need to clarify precisely what it is that you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [copy constructor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_constructor), be it in the syntax `T object(object_to_copy)` or `T object = object_to_copy` construct the new object, so doesn't require that it already exists.  This is documented in the C++ standard, section 12.8/2.

The ordinary assignment operator, which is used in other context than copy construction above, does require the target object to already exist (i.e. must be constructed).  This can easlily be deduced from section 13.5 of the standard.

Comment: @jrok no it's not, and I was hoping that my first paragraph was pretty clear about that.   I'll add "which" in the second sentence to remove the ambiguity that you've spotted.

Answer (score 0):

What I can get from your question is you want to ask whether in `a = b`, should `a` be fully constructed.

In that case answer is yes, `a` should be a fully constructed object before assignment operator is called on that. Because assignment only makes sense between two objects not between object and some random raw bits.

Answer (score 0):

On the contrary to the other answers, I will say that the `operator=` can be called before the object is constructed. I believe the following code is valid and doesn't provoke undefined behaviour.

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
  public:
    A(){
      std::cout << "A()\n";
      *this = *this;
    }
    A(const A&  a) { std::cout << "A(const A&  a)\n"; }
    A& operator=(const A& a) { std::cout << "operator=\n"; return *this; }
};

int main()
{
  A a;
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
A()
operator=
```

Of course it doesn't make any sense. However, the question is whether something is allowed, my answer yes it is. Clearly `operator=` is called before the constructor ended and one is allowed to write such a construction.

Comment: a class is fully constructed when the initialiser list has been actioned. That is, by the time the program flow hits the opening `{` in the constructor, the object is constructed. The code between the braces in a constructor should be regarded as 'post-construction'

Comment: Dang. I will delete the answer, but can I get a quote from the standard or  a pointer where I can find the quote? Just for myself.

Comment: A constructor can call any member function. We don't really need to refer to the standard to verify this.

Comment: here's a good explanation of it all.
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list

Comment: @n.m. I wasn't asking about it. I was asking where it is written that object is considered being constructed after the initialization list rather then execution of the body of constructor. It's not so obvious. E.g: If a constructor throws an exception in the body a constructor, was it constructed or not?

Comment: Whatever was not constructed, does not get destructed. Which destructors are called when a constructor throws? Not the "current" one. That's the answer I suppose.

Comment: You can catch exceptions thrown in the body of a constructor. You can't catch the ones thrown in the initialisation list - precisely because at that point there is no way to recover the object since it's not yet constructed.

Comment: Yes, you can catch exceptions thrown in the initialization list: http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/066.htm.